# TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, reactjs, this

I am trying to setState of a component after a ajax callback receives data from REST api. here's my code for the component constructor

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { posts: [] };
    this.getPosts = this.getPosts.bind(this);
}
```

Then I have a `componentDidMount` method that looks like following.

```
componentDidMount() {
        this.getPosts();
}
```

Now here's my getPosts function where I am doing the ajax request.

```
getPosts = () =>  {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: urlname,
        success: function(data) {
            this.setState( { posts: data } )
        }
    });
}
```

I am tying to set the State but I am getting the following error.

```
this.setState is not a function
```

Not really sure what is causing this. It would be really helpful if someone points me to the right direction. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bind the callback function also so that `this` inside the callback points to the context of the React Component and not the callback function

```
getPosts = () =>  {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: urlname,
        success: (data) => {
            this.setState( { posts: data } )
        }
    });
}
```

or you could use bind like

```
getPosts = () =>  {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: urlname,
        success: function(data) {
            this.setState({ posts: data })
        }.bind(this)
    });
}
```

Comment: No problem, glad to have helped. This is a common mistake that most people do. I will recommend you to look into binding whenver you get such an error in future

Answer (score 4):

The issue is related with loosing context of [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).
Please try this:

```
let self = this;
getPosts = () =>  {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: urlname,
        success: function(data) {
            self.setState( { posts: data } )
        }
    });
}
```

or you can use bind:

```
getPosts = () =>  {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: urlname,
            success: function(data) {
                self.setState( { posts: data } )
            }
        });
    }.bind(this)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to store the context into a variable as "this" reference will not be available in the callback. Try below solution:

```
getPosts = () =>  {
let that=this;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: urlname,
        success: function(data) {
            that.setState( { posts: data } )
        }
    });
}
```