# React.js - Cannot read property 'strikes' of undefined error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
render() {
return (
  <div className="container">
    <LightningCounterDisplay/>
  </div>
   );
  }
}

class LightningCounter extends Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  strikes : 0
};
}
timerTick() {
 this.setState({
  strikes: this.state.strikes + 100
 });
}
componentDidMount() {
setInterval(this.timerTick, 1000);
 }
render() {
  return (
  <h1>{this.state.strikes}</h1>
  );
 }
}

class LightningCounterDisplay extends Component {
 render() {
 const divStyle = {
  width: 250,
  textAligh: "center",
  backgroundColor: "black",
  padding: 40,
  fontFamily: "sans-serif",
  color: "#999",
  borderRadius: 10
}
return (
  <div style={divStyle}>
    <LightningCounter/>
  </div>

  );
 }
}

export default App;
```

I started studying react.js and es6 from yesterday.

I tried to make a part that increased by 100 in one second.
but, it occurs TypeError: Cannot read property 'strikes' of undefined.

Can you tell where the problem is?
How should I fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44257176/typeerror-cannot-read-property-setstate-of-undefined)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to use bind, alternatively you can also use arrow function for timerTick

```js
timerTick = () => {
 this.setState(prevState => ({
  strikes: prevState.strikes + 100
 }));
}
```

with arrow function, using `setInterval(this.timerTick, 1000);` would work.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it through 'bind'.

```
componentDidMount() {
  setInterval(this.timerTick.bind(this), 1000);
}
```

It works, but is this the right solution?