# setState Undefinded error from fetch request

Tags: node.js, rest, api, reactjs, webpack

This fetch request:

```
  var url = 'api/assetName/?id='+id;
  fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    credentials: 'include',
    body: JSON.stringify({
      ids: vehiclesT
    })}
  ).then(data => {
      return data.json();
    }).then( json => {
      console.log(json);
      console.log(json);
      this.setState({
        vehicles: json
      });
    });
```

Is throwing this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined
```

Basically why is this and how can I fix it?

Thanks, Ed.

Comment: This code is in an react component ?

Comment: The problem could be that you are not binding the function which contains the fetch request

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Add the class that contains the function doing `fetch`, please.

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44257176/typeerror-cannot-read-property-setstate-of-undefined/44257242#44257242

Comment: I don't think ES6 funcitons have a `this` object. `this.setState` is therefore inaccessible.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44257176/typeerror-cannot-read-property-setstate-of-undefined/44257242#44257242 fixed it, if you want to post it as an answer I'll gladly mark it as correct. Thanks man.

Comment: @EdLynch. Glad it helped . However if that question solved the issue, i will mark this one as a duplicate