# React - setting state to display a message for validation errors in form leads to :Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined - Why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, express

I have a signup form and from server side, I check if field is empty, if it is, then I res.send("xxx"), then from fronend I want to set state to a message to be displayed. With my code (below) I am getting the error 'Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined' and I don't understand why?! Thanks!!

```
class Signup extends React.Component{

 constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        firstnameVlidation:"",
        lastnameVlidation:"",
        firstname: '',
        lastname: '',
    }
    this.registering = this.registering.bind(this);
 }
}

 registering(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
    var info = {
        "firstname": this.state.firstname,
        "lastname": this.state.lastname
         ...
    }
    axis.post('/signup', {info})
      .then(function(res){
         return res.data
       })
       .then(function(response){
          if (response === 'no') {
            this.setState({
                firstnameVlidation:"Enter Firstname"
            })
          }
        })
  }
....
```

my backend route:

```
....
  if (req.body.firstname.length<1){
    res.send("no")
  }
....
```

Comment: What else do you have in `registering`? Is if condition wrapped inside of some function?

Comment: Why are you binding `handleInput` to `registering`? Shouldn't you be binding `registering` to `registering`?

Comment: @Talha I update my question with the rest of my code

Comment: @ Lansana sorry it was just a mistake in my code here, its fine in my actual code so that has nothing to do with the error. I updated my question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44257176/typeerror-cannot-read-property-setstate-of-undefined)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function inside the `.then` statement is not bound to the context of the react component object. You can change:

```
function(response) {
...
}
```

to

```
response => {
...
}
```

to have this anonymous function automatically bound, and then `this` will be defined correctly.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Its works now. Could you please explain that? I thought until now its just a different syntax of es6 -how can it change the context?

Comment: The value of `this` inside a function depends on how and where the function is called. You can force it to have the right context by *binding* the function to a specific context, and the fat arrow (`=>`) function is another way to force binding `this` to the context where the function is defined. See this section of [You Don't Know JS](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/tree/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes) for more details.