# use axios with react to get data from api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am trying to use axios to get data from the api (https://reqres.in/) and display in my react app. Before this I fetched the data from the API using fetch method in javascript. Now I have tried coding this from various resources. How should I do it. Is it the correct method?

My app.js file-

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css'; 
import axios from 'axios';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  this.successShow = this.successShow.bind(this);
  this.errorShow = this.errorShow.bind(this);
}
componentDidMount() {
 axios.get('https://reqres.in/api/products/3')
   .then(function (response) {
     this.successShow(response);
   })
   .catch(function (error) {
     this.errorShow(error);
   });
 }
successShow(response) {
 this.member = <pre>{JSON.stringify(response.data, null, '\t')}</pre> ;
}
errorShow(error) {
 this.member = <pre>{JSON.stringify(error.response.data, null, '\t')}</pre>;
}
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Welcome to React</h2>
      <h3>{JSON.stringify(this.state.person.data)}</h3>
      <div>{this.member}</div>
    </div>
  );
  }
 }
export default App;
```

---

It also gives the error - Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'errorShow' of undefined.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44257176/typeerror-cannot-read-property-setstate-of-undefined)

Comment: One of the key things about arrow functions is that they don't create their own new scope, they remain in the current scope

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Changes:**

**1.** You need to bind `this` with then and catch callback methods, use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

**2.** You didn't define the initial state and using `this.state.person.data` it will throw error.

**3.** Storing the UI in state or global variable is not a good idea, ui part should be inside render method only.

Write it like this:

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            person: {}
        }
        //this.successShow = this.successShow.bind(this);
        //this.errorShow = this.errorShow.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('https://reqres.in/api/products/3')
        .then((response) => {
            this.successShow(response);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            this.successShow(error);
        });
    }

    successShow(response) {
        this.setState({
            person: response.data
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
              <h2>Welcome to React</h2>
              <h3>{JSON.stringify(this.state.person.data)}</h3>

              <pre>{JSON.stringify(this.state.person.data)}</pre>

              <div>{this.member}</div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for the answer,it works. But I didn't understand your first point.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `this.errorShow()` inside of the `function`, `this` is not your component object, but context of `function`. You should use arrow functions instead, arrow functions do not create its own `this` so you can access your component `this`:

```
componentDidMount() {
 axios.get('https://reqres.in/api/products/3')
   .then((response) => {
     this.successShow(response);
   })
   .catch(error) => {
     this.errorShow(error);
   });
 }
```

[More info about arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
componentDidMount() {
 axios.get('https://reqres.in/api/products/3')
   .then((response) => {
     this.successShow(response);
   })
   .catch((error) => {
     this.errorShow(error);
   });
 }
```

Use `arrow functions` to remain the right scope of `this`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `this` in your `then` and `catch` callbacks doesn't refer to your class, but to the default (global) scope. You need to bind the right this. You actually already have the appropriate functions set up with this binding, so you can just use them directly:

```
componentDidMount() {
  axios.get('https://reqres.in/api/products/3')
   .then(this.successShow)
   .catch(this.errorShow);
}
```

In general, you can also use `=>` function syntax, which inherits the 'this' from the scope the function is declared in, rather than using the global scope. E.g.

```
componentDidMount() {
  axios.get('https://reqres.in/api/products/3')
   .then(success => this.successShow(success))
   .catch(error => this.errorShow(error));
}
```

(note the `=>` functions are completely unnecessary here of course).

You have an additional problem, which is the you need to store `member` in component state (`this.state.member`), not just as a field, and use the `setState` function to update it. Otherwise your component won't re-render when you update `member`.