# How to loop and map value from API inside JSX in React.js?

Tags: reactjs

How to loop and map value from API inside JSX in React.js? And for mapping what are the thing I've to import?
My Code:

```
eventlistClick (){
     var apiBaseUrl = "http://api.eventsacross-stage.railsfactory.com/api/";
     var input = this.state.search_event;
     axios.get(apiBaseUrl+'v1/events/?on_dashboard=false'+input)
     .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        for(var i = 0; i < response.data.events_count; i++) {
          var obj = response.data.events[i];
          console.log(obj.name);
        }
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
```

I want to print the "obj.name" after "Events Name"

```
render(){
   return (...
       <div className="col-sm-5">
          <button
            className="btn btn-default"
            type='submit'
            onClick={this.eventlistClick.bind(this)}>
            <i className="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
          </button>
            <h1 className="text-center">Events List</h1>
            <div className="panel panel-default">
              <div className="panel-heading">Event Name</div>
              <div className="panel-body">
                <p>Description</p>
                <p>URL</p>
                <p>City</p>
                <p>Date [Start At - End At]</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
);
}
```

Comment: Save the axios response in state and then map over the state object as described in the answer to the duplicate question

Comment: this.state = obj;        is it the way to store?

Comment: use setState, this.setState({events: response.data.events }) inside the success callback and also bind the function and the success callback

Comment: constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      search_event: ''
    }
    this.onClick = this.eventlistClick.bind(this);
  }

Comment: how to bind success callback?

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44257176/typeerror-cannot-read-property-setstate-of-undefined/44257242#44257242

Comment: Now i'm getting this error after adding "Cannot read property 'state' of undefined"

Comment: See the question that I added in the comments, you need to bind the function eventlistclick and also the `.then` callback

Comment: actually I want the data on the loading of the page not on any button click. Can you please help?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157862/discussion-between-riya-kapuria-and-shubham-khatri).

Comment: check my comment on the chatRoom discussion.

Comment: Plese check my modified code on the chatRoom discussion.